# plotly world map animation not behaving as expected

Tags: python, animation, plotly, plotly-python

i am trying to generate an animation using plotly of a world map, with lines drawn between countries representing interactions between countries, and the width of the lines representing the frequency of the interaction. The animation is to show the changes in these interactions over different periods.

i have checked things at each stage of the code, and it all seems to be working as expected up until the actual construction of the animation. the output is an animation, but the behavior is not as expected. I seem to be losing lines (only some of the interactions are showing up in the animation)

I dont have experience with plotly, thanks in advance!

this is a snippet of what my data looks like

```
    From    To  Frequency   Period  From_lat_long   To_lat_long
11442   VIETNAM SLOVAKIA    3   2019-2022   (15.9266657, 107.9650855)   (48.7411522, 19.4528646)
11443   VIETNAM SLOVENIA    1   2019-2022   (15.9266657, 107.9650855)   (46.1199444, 14.8153333)
11444   VIETNAM SRI LANKA   1   2019-2022   (15.9266657, 107.9650855)   (7.877395849999999, 80.66247852355892)
11445   VIETNAM TANZANIA    1   2019-2022   (15.9266657, 107.9650855)   (-6.5247123, 35.7878438)
11446   VIETNAM TUNISIA 1   2019-2022   (15.9266657, 107.9650855)   (33.8439408, 9.400138)
```

I want lines drawn between the From country to the To country, with line widths weighted to the frequency column. And as you see, I have the latitude and longitude coordinates of each country already.

These are the blocks of code, along with what is happening at each step.

```
# Define the periods
periods = list(data["Period"].unique())

# Create an empty list to store the frames
frames = []

# Loop through each period
for period in periods:
    # Create a data frame for the current period
    data_period = data.query(f"Period == '{period}'")

    # Create a trace for each country
    traces = []
    for country in set(data_period["From"]).union(set(data_period["To"])):
        df_country = data_period.query(f"`From` == '{country}' or `To` == '{country}'")
        if not data_period[data_period["From"] == country].empty:
            line_width = data_period[data_period["From"] == country][
                "Frequency"
            ].values[0]
        elif not data_period[data_period["To"] == country].empty:
            line_width = data_period[data_period["To"] == country]["Frequency"].values[
                0
            ]
        else:
            line_width = 1
        traces.append(
            go.Scattergeo(
                locationmode="country names",
                lon=df_country["From_lat_long"].apply(lambda x: x[1]).tolist()
                + [df_country["To_lat_long"].iloc[-1][1]],
                lat=df_country["From_lat_long"].apply(lambda x: x[0]).tolist()
                + [df_country["To_lat_long"].iloc[-1][0]],
                mode="lines",
                line=dict(width=line_width, color="red"),
                name=country,
            )
        )

    # Create the figure for this period
    fig_period = go.Figure(data=traces)
    fig_period.update_layout(
        title_text=f"Country interactions for {period}",
        geo=dict(
            projection=dict(type="natural earth"),
            showland=True,
            landcolor="rgb(243, 243, 243)",
            countrycolor="rgb(204, 204, 204)",
        ),
    )

    # Add this figure to the frames list as a frame
    frames.append(fig_period)
```

This is behaving as expected. I can call frame[12] for example and the output is:

[output of frame[12]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUMgy.png)

```
# Create an empty figure and add the first frame to it
fig = go.Figure(frames[0])

# Update the layout of the figure
fig.update_layout(
    title_text="Country interactions",
    geo=dict(
        projection=dict(type="natural earth"),
        showland=True,
        landcolor="rgb(243, 243, 243)",
        countrycolor="rgb(204, 204, 204)",
    ),
)
```

This part seems to work as well, but im not certain if its the correct approach

```
# create all the new frames
new_frames = [
    go.Frame(data=frame["data"], layout=frame["layout"]) for frame in frames[1:]
]
fig.frames = new_frames
```

this step also works, but possibly the error lies here?

```
# create the animation

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            type="buttons",
            showactive=True,
            buttons=[
                dict(
                    label="Play",
                    method="animate",
                    args=[None, {"frame": {"duration": 500, "redraw": True}, "fromcurrent": True, "transition": {"duration": 2000, "easing": "cubic-in-out", "blur": 10}, "traces": [i for i in range(len(frames[21]['data']))]}],
                ),
                dict(
                    label="Pause",
                    method="animate",
                    args=[[None], {"frame": {"duration": 0, "redraw": False}, "mode": "immediate", "transition": {"duration": 0}}],
                ),
            ],
        )
    ]
)
```

this step creates an animation, but i am missing most of the lines.

for example, this is the corresponding image for frame[12] in the animation

[corresponding image for frame[12] in the animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzmYV.png)

Any help would be appreciated!